# How to disable scroll left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a **div element** ("`#parent`") that includes multiple child elements ("`.item`"). I want to enable scrolling the parent element just in **one direction** (left **OR** right). Otherwise nothing should happen.

---

See my code:

```js
$("#parent").scroll(function() {
    // >>> scroll event
    // >>> console.log("SCROLLED " + new Date().getMilliseconds())
})
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>
    <div class="child">12</div>
    <div class="child">13</div>
    <div class="child">14</div>
    <div class="child">15</div>
    <div class="child">16</div>
    <div class="child">17</div>
    <div class="child">18</div>
    <div class="child">19</div>
    <div class="child">20</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**So to my question:** I'd like to disable scrolling the element to the right hand side (backwards). I'd like to just enable the scroll of the items to the left hand side (forward).

**How can I use jQuery to implement this method?** Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the job<sup>1</sup>.

`previousX` stores the last position that the element was scrolled to on the X axis.

When the scroll event triggers, `newX` is set to the `scrollLeft()` value (this returns how far the element has been scrolled from it's left-most side, in pixels).

- If this value is **greater** than `previousX`, then they have scrolled to the right, so we allow the scroll, and update `previousX` to the new x value.
- If the value is **lesser** than `previousX`, they have scrolled to the right - so we need to cancel the scroll. To do this, we can use the `scrollLeft()` function again - but this time, we provide a value to it - this allows us to set the scroll position; rather than retrieve it. By setting it to `previousX`, we can prevent the scroll.
- Note that if the value is **equal**, we do nothing.

```js
let previousX = -1;

$("#parent").scroll(function(e){
    let newX = $("#parent").scrollLeft();
    if (newX>previousX) {
        previousX = newX;
    }
    else if (newX<previousX) {
        $("#parent").scrollLeft(previousX);
    }
})
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>
    <div class="child">12</div>
    <div class="child">13</div>
    <div class="child">14</div>
    <div class="child">15</div>
    <div class="child">16</div>
    <div class="child">17</div>
    <div class="child">18</div>
    <div class="child">19</div>
    <div class="child">20</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: *Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work at all when I use it with my Magic Trackpad - but when dragging the scroll bars it works just fine. I haven't tested it on a touch-screen device / Windows / using a proper mouse & scroll wheel, so I don't know how it behaves in those cases either. It would definitely be worth you doing some proper testing / improving this code, as it probably will not work in all cases, or even catch all possible scroll events.*

Comment: I already found some kind of solution on my own: Using nearly the same code like you. Just added the lines: `e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();`  - However. Using a trackpad for me looks **super** ugly&sticky - no idea how to fix this `:)`

Comment: Yeah, I definitely agree. The trackpad thing is what makes this hard. I think the only real solution would be to completely capture the scroll event, and then implement the scrolling yourself.