# How to prevent scroll direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Note**: This question is an *update* to [How to disable scroll left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075387/how-to-disable-scroll-left/50075973?noredirect=1#comment87168113_50075973).

---

I'd like to get an div-element that is just scrollable into ONE directions *(in my case only "right")*. Scrolling to the left direction should get canceled.

I've developed some jQuery code that should be able to prevent the scrolling in the unwanted direction, what kind of **is working** so far!

But I got some issues because scrolling to the prevented direction obviously looks super *sticky & ugly*.

```js
let value = $("#parent").scrollLeft()

$("#parent").scroll(function(e) {
  let direction = (this.scrollLeft > value) ? 'right' : ((this.scrollLeft === value) ? false : 'left');
  console.log(direction)

  if (direction == "left") {
    this.scrollLeft = value;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  value = $("#parent").scrollLeft()
})
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: gray;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
   height: 20px!important;
}
.as-console-row {
   background: green!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>
    <div class="child">12</div>
    <div class="child">13</div>
    <div class="child">14</div>
    <div class="child">15</div>
    <div class="child">16</div>
    <div class="child">17</div>
    <div class="child">18</div>
    <div class="child">19</div>
    <div class="child">20</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have a look: **Scrolling back** looks super ugly:

[image: Gif]

How to fix this?

Comment: I'm using Chrome(65.0.3325.181 64bit) and the scroll bar just fixed when I tried to scroll to left, didn't run into your situation.

Comment: this looks like a really poor approach and you would be better creating your own controls rather than using native scroll bar

Comment: Your right, seems to be a performance problem of Safari @Hikarunomemory

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "poor approach" - if you don't mind maybe you like to share some code for your idea! @charlietfl

Comment: There are many many content slider script demos all over the web. Also custom html scroll bars

Comment: Thats really a petty that nobody is able to fix the problem. Too bad :/